# PHP google geocoding service returns zero results

Tags: php, geocoding, google-geocoder

I have a problem when I try to convert an address into latitude and longitude via google service. My address is 1456 sok. no: 10/1 kat:8 Alsancak. The problem is when I write this address to url, correct result is returned, however when I use the php code below, I get zero results.

No problem with result :

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1456%20sok.%20no:%2010/1%20kat:8%20Alsancak&sensor=true

Problem with php :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


getGoogleAddressCoordinates("1456 sok. no: 10/1 kat:8 Alsancak");

function getGoogleAddressCoordinates($address)
{
 //$address = urlencode($address);
 $address = str_replace(" ", "%20", $address);

 $request = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address . '&sensor=true');
 $json = json_decode($request, true);
 print_r ($json);


}
```

?>

Comment: What exactly do you get back from the request? (What does `$request` contain?) if it's `false`, something went wrong with the  call itself. Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: the link doesn't work for me..I get `ZERO_RESULTS`

Answer (score 0):

The address `1456 sok. no: 10/1 kat:8 Alsancak` is not valid. If you try it in google maps you get zero results, too.

Try it with: `1456 sok. 10/1 Alsancak` and uncomment the line `$address = urlencode($address);` and clear the line `$address = str_replace(" ", "%20", $address);`.

The url should look like:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1456%20sok.%2010%2F1%20Alsancak&sensor=true